# mysqldump - sorting table output to avoid forward references in foreign keys

Tags: mysql, sql, ddl

I'm currently attempting to create a script that will:

- process a mysql schema and dump the descriptions of tables in the schema,
- translate the MySQL-specific parts of the resulting DDL to another database system's equivalent (currently targeting H2, but any database that runs in-process in a Java environment and supports memory tables would be appropriate if I need to switch), and
- then recreates them in a schema in the new database system.

Currently, I'm using `mysqldump` to perform the first part of the operation, and a sequence of string/regexp substitutions to perform the second.

The problem I have is that `mysqldump` is producing output with tables that have foreign keys before the tables they reference.  This isn't a problem for mysql because in mysql you can just disable constraint checking and then create them -- unfortunately, while H2 does have an option for disabling constraints, it only applies to data changes and not table creation.

I'd really rather not have to parse the SQL enough to identify the correct order of the tables myself, as it seems at least vaguely tricky to do it right.

Therefore, is there either (1) any way to get mysqldump to produce the tables in the correct order or (2) an alternative approach to produce the correct order?

(I'm aware that it is at least theoretically possible to have a schema where no correct order is possible, but I know none of the schemas I'm likely to work with have this problem, so this isn't something I need to worry about)